# Why the uncertainty principle can be used for estimation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

It is usually said/done in textbooks and classes that if $\Delta x$ is known then $\Delta p_x$ can be estimated using the uncertainty principle as $\Delta p_x \sim \hbar/\Delta x$.

But the uncertainty principle does not say that, it says $\Delta p_x\ge\hbar/\Delta x$. That means we can only set a lower bound on $\Delta p_x$, i.e. $\Delta p_x$ could be anything between $\hbar/\Delta x$ and $\infty$

Why then the lower bound is chosen for estimation?

Are there certain situations where the products in uncertainties is of the same order as $\hbar$?

Answer (score 2):

It assumes a sort of democracy between $x$ and $p$, and is obviously not valid everywhere. The connection between classical and quantum mechanics happens through coherent states, which are states which minimize the product $\Delta p \Delta x$, and in a sense, behave most classically (and have well-defined classical limits as $\hbar \to 0$).

So if you started with a something behaving reasonably classically, e.g. an electron's motion in a uniform electric field, and you wanted to estimate the uncertainty of it's momentum, you could use this as a starting point. There's nothing really rigorous about it, other than the fact that coherent states seem to  enjoy a privileged status in nature.

Comment: I did not ask for rigorous. It is only an estimation. My problem is the estimation is based on an inequality. So I can estimate something to be n or one million times bigger than n. Sorry I am not sure that I understand your answer. I do not know what coherent states are. Are you saying that in certain situations the uncertainty product can be of the same order as $\hbar$?

Comment: Yes. The ground state of the harmonic oscillator is an example of a coherent state, and satisfies $\Delta x \Delta p = \frac{\hbar}{2}$.

Comment: But the cases in which the uncertainty principle is used for estimation are so different from the harmonic oscillator. Or is it because that we are assuming that the particle is localized by a gaussian wave packet (which is the harmonic oscillator ground state)?

Comment: Yes, it's the wave-packet assumption. Can you give an example of where you have encountered this?

Comment: Introductory Physics/ Modern physics textbooks. How about energy time uncertainty relations? do coherent states hit the lower bound also?

Comment: Time-uncertainty relations aren't bona-fide uncertainty relations, and I don't see any reason that coherence states would, but you could check.

Comment: But the energy time uncertainty relation is used the same way to estimate the life time of unstable particles, knowing their mass distribution. Oh but if the mass distribution is gaussian then the uncertainty in time times that of energy must be of the same order of magnitude as $\hbar$ right?

Comment: As long as the wave packet, or the state of the system looks like a gaussian with no crazy features or many nodes then we expect that the uncertainty in position time that of momentum will be of the same order of magnitude as $\hbar$ right?

Comment: Not necessarily, see [squeezed states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeezed_coherent_state)

Comment: @Revo Actually Lionel's pinpoints a bit of an unsolved mystery with macroscopic states. As in Lionel's comments, all coherent states saturate the inequality (it becomes an equality) and, for some reason, we seem to see states that behave "coherently" in our macroscopy world unless we do a great deal of painstaking work to set up either squeezed or entangled states. For example, a classical solution of Maxwell's equations describes a coherent optical state, which is wholly defined by the mean of the $\hat{E}_j$ and $\hat{H}_j$ observables (similarly, some classical probability ....

Comment: @Revo .... distributions are defined by one parameter, say a Poisson distribution) as a function of position and time. Entangled and squeezed states need much more info to define fully (some classical pdfs - gaussian, for instance - need more info that simply their means). So a general quantum state is much more complicated. Yet we have the *experimental* observation, as yet not fully explained, that things tend to "come up coherent in the wash". Lionel is essentially using this *experimental* observation.

Comment: I wonder if there is a quantum version of the central limit theorem hiding somewhere.